# How to remove a cloudwatch event rule using aws cli?

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using `terraform destroy` to destroy some resource. However it failed at this step:

> - module.restore_db_from_snapshot.aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule:
>     aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule: AccessDeniedException: User:
>     arn:aws:sts::941225788888:assumed-role/delete/anthony_credentials is
>     not authorized to perform: events:DescribeRule on resource:
>     arn:aws:events:us-east-2:941225788888:rule/dev-crazy_rule
>       status code: 400, request id: da4284e5-3b00-4a24-9798-fcb6915c94cb

Apparently my profile does not have sufficient right to call `events:DescribeRule`. However I think my profile still have the permission to drop it.

That's why I want to use `aws` cli to directly drop the event rule, maybe with the ARN as shown in the error message.

However when I check the `cloudwatch` subcommandd, it does not have any `delete` of event rules.

Is it possible for me to drop the event rule via aws cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `events` service [`delete-rule` subcommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/delete-rule.html):

```
aws events delete-rule --name <rule_name>
```

You need to also make sure you have deleted any of the event's targets with [`events remove-targets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/remove-targets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bit old question but,
I made a bash script to automate it:

https://gist.github.com/maurostorch/0a03da8770f9c798d964cb67befae935